# Enable the calculator mode button

Tags: button, mode, calculator

I'd like to use advance mode and programming mode in calculator. but it is not showing mode option button in 16.04 ubuntu. How to enable the calculator mode button.

Comment: Are you using Unity or GNOME3?

Answer (score 1):

As of unity launched, Ubuntu used the Global menu feature that places the menu bar for each application on the bar at the top of the screen. So, if you wish to change anything for an application, you will need to hover over the top task bar while focusing on the application.

[image]

Otherwise, there are few command you can use for changing Calculator mode without accessing this hidden menu.

Basic mode :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.calculator button-mode basic; gnome-calculator
```

Advanced mode :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.calculator button-mode advanced; gnome-calculator
```

Financial mode :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.calculator button-mode financial; gnome-calculator
```

Programming mode :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.calculator button-mode programming; gnome-calculator
```

Keyboard mode :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.calculator button-mode keyboard; gnome-calculator
```